# Terraform - Multiple Conditional

Tags: terraform, keycloak, hcl, hashicorp

I would like some help regarding Terraform.

I'm creating a Terraform module to add already existing users in Keycloak in already existing groups.

```
resource "keycloak_user_groups" "user_groups" {
  #for_each = local.keycloak_users_lc
  realm_id   = local.keycloak_realm_data_lc
  #user_id    = each.key.id
  user_id    = data.keycloak_user.keycloak_users_base[count.index].id
  exhaustive = false

  group_ids = [
    data.keycloak_group.keycloak_group_base[count.index].id
  ]
}
```

According to the code above, an attempt was made to use **count** and **for_each**, but both were unsuccessful.

The idea would be, in tfstate I put the username and the group I want to add to. (1 or more, list).

With these values, I created 2 data_source, one for **data "keycloak_group" "keycloak_group_base"** and another for **data "keycloak_user" "keycloak_users_base"**.

And with this return I use the **resource "keycloak_user_groups" "user_groups"**.

Because I needed to create these data_source instead of using the fixed value, as the resource needs the **ID** of both the user and the group.

Follow the project files:

**main.tf (module)**

```
locals {
  keycloak_realm_data_lc    = data.terraform_remote_state.realm.outputs.keycloak_realmid_out_mol
  keycloak_role_base_add_lc = var.keycloak_role_base_add
  keycloak_group_base_add_lc = var.keycloak_group_base_add
  keycloak_users_lc         = var.keycloak_users
}

data "keycloak_role" "keycloak_role_base" {
  realm_id = local.keycloak_realm_data_lc
  name     = local.keycloak_role_base_add_lc
}

data "keycloak_group" "keycloak_group_base" {
  #for_each = local.keycloak_group_base_add_lc
  count = length(local.keycloak_group_base_add_lc)
  realm_id = local.keycloak_realm_data_lc
  #name     = each.key
  name = local.keycloak_group_base_add_lc[count.index]
}

data "keycloak_user" "keycloak_users_base" {
  #for_each = local.keycloak_users_lc
  count = length(local.keycloak_users_lc)
  realm_id = local.keycloak_realm_data_lc
  #username = each.key
  username = local.keycloak_users_lc[count.index]
}

## 8. INCLUDE USERS IN GROUP
resource "keycloak_user_groups" "user_groups" {
  #for_each = local.keycloak_users_lc
  realm_id   = local.keycloak_realm_data_lc
  #user_id    = each.key.id
  user_id    = data.keycloak_user.keycloak_users_base[count.index].id
  exhaustive = false

  group_ids = [
    data.keycloak_group.keycloak_group_base[count.index].id
  ]
}
```

**vars.tf (profile)**

```
module "keycloak_add_user" {
  source = "../../modules/path"

  keycloak_role_base_add = "access"
  keycloak_group_base_add = ["g_cad"]
  keycloak_squad         = "myaccount"
  keycloak_users = ["cad01", "cad02"]
}
```

***keycloak_group_base_add*** = One group or more

***keycloak_users*** = One user or more

The expectation is:

The **keycloak_role_base** data source reads the list of groups declared in the variable **local.keycloak_role_base_add_lc**, go to the keycloak and look for the list of group IDs to fill in the **user_groups** resource.

The **keycloak_users_base** data source reads the list of users declared in the variable **local.keycloak_realm_data_lc**, go to Keycloak and fetch the list of user IDs to fill in the **user_groups** resource.

Comment: If there are any errors, please add them to the question.